# simplest application possible that needs multiple (two) JVMs

Tags: java, akka-typed

I have an actor system "Main" running potentially forever. This main actor understands "Snapshot" or "Stop" messages (defined by me).

I would like to create a bash script that, while Main actor is running, launches a second (short lived) system, or actor, or whatever and sends a snapshot or stop message to the Main actor.

With akka classic that was very easy with actorSelection from a secondary actor

```
ActorRef mainActorRef = Await.result(system.actorSelection("akka.main.actor.path").resolveOne(timeout));

mainActorRef.send(new StopMessage() or new SnapsthotMessage());
```

What is the analogous and hopefully equally easy solution in akka typed?

Comment: `system.tell( new StopMessage() ); ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's try to sort this mess a bit... First of all, your question is highly unclear:

In the title, you ask for something based on two JVMs, but in the text you ask for a "*second (short lived) system, or actor, or whatever*". No clue if multiple JVMs are a requirement or just an idea to solve this. Additionally, your example code is something that - disregarding clustering - works in one JVM and you also only mention a second "*actor*" there.

So, if the requirement is using two JVMs, then I would suggest making it more clear in what way, why, etc. Then people can also actually provide help for that part.

For now, let me assume you want to simply have...

1. A (typed) actor system
2. ...that can somehow process `StopMessage`/`SnapshotMessage`...
3. ...both of which can be triggered from the outside

The way you can do this very simply is the usual typed way:

1. Define a RootGuardian actor that accepts those two messages (that actor is basically what the implicit /user actor was in classic) - you have to do that for your Typed actor system anyway (because to setup a typed actor system, you supply the behavior of the RootGuardian).
2. Let it create the needed child actors to process those messages (either at start or when needed). Of course, in your simple example, the root guardian can also process these messages itself, but an actorsystem with only one actor is not a very typical use-case.
3. Let it delegate the messages to the appropriate child actor(s)
4. Add a simple api endpoint to call `system.tell ( ... )` to send the message into the system, where your RootGuardian actor will delegate it correctly.
5. Use curl to call your api endpoint (or use any other way to communicate with your application, there are dozens, but most of them are outside the scope of akka itself)

As a general idea, Akka Typed tends to be much more strict about who can send what messages where. In Akka classic, it was easy to basically send everything everywhere and find and access any actor from everywhere, including outside the system. Unfortunately, this "freedom" leads to a huge amount of problems and was thus severely limited in Typed, which makes for clearer contracts and better defined message flows.

Of course, in a highly complex system, you might, for example, want to use a `Receptionist` instead to find the target actor for your specific message, but since the question was for a simple application, I would skip that for now.

You can, of course, also add ways to get your ActorRefs outside the system, for example by using the Ask Pattern to implement something like an actor discovery in the RootGuardian, but there is simply no need to try to circumvent the concepts of Akka Typed by re-implementing ActorSelection.

Obviously you also could use clustering, start up a 2nd JVM, connect it to the cluster, send the message and shut it down again, but we can assume that this would be overkill and very, very slow (waiting for long seconds while starting up the app, connecting to the cluster, etc. just to then use a few milliseconds to send the message).

If you absolutely want a 2nd JVM there, you can, of course, for example, create simply REST client that sends the message and start that, but... **curl exists**, so... what for?

So, tl;dr: The "analogous and hopefully equally easy solution" is  `system.tell( new StopMessage() );`, which is basically the same in akka typed as the code for akka classic you provided. Obviously, implementing the actor system in a way that this code works, is the (slightly) more tricky part.

Comment: I disagree, but my message could confuse you even more, and you wouldn't be no more able to do a job related with informatics.

Comment: done. I implemented the solution based on this answer.